Tektro HD-M275 replacement brake pads
What are replacement brake pads for Tektro HD-M275 hydraulic brakes? According to Tektro's poor website, no brake pad is compatible nor any are listed near the M275 description :-S but I guess (and what I read) that any E10.11 brake pads will do. From description on various sellers M275 is sometimes listed as compatible, more often not.
Scratching my head how is this confusion even possible...

Tektro lists the tektro e10.11 pads as standard, and the p20.11 as an option.
https://www.tektro.com/upload/Sd9b9hLtYhZnzPQ1d8Fs_1676605167.pdf
Shimano's B05SRX are compatible based on my own experience and previous research a long time ago. The shimano pads are less expensive where I live and all three mentioned pads are resin-type /non-metallic pads so they should be fine with any disc/rotor you have on your setup.
I have tried e10.11 and B05SRX with great results and no issues. No big differences either, perhaps the Shimano ones are slightly more prone to squeeling noises*, but I still prefer them due to the lower price.
*)which is funny since I just now see that Tektro brand them as "less noise" pads in the pdf, so perhaps they actually do squeel a bit less.

Where did you even find this PDF? Anyway, curiously when I check their E10.11 on Amazon.de, HD-M275 for some reason isn't listed. I guess this is more of a lazy descriptions than anything else. https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Tektro-E10-11-Organic-Compound-STB1788/dp/B07V2XZVJ6/

It's from Tektro's own site. The web us full of incomplete and sometimes wrong information. Your link even lists the pads as meant for "motorbikes" and "rear" position. Both of which i'm pretty sure is just wrong if these are the tektro e10.11 pads. The picture looks like the product I have bought myself a few times.

Yep, any of the standard B01S shaped pads will work. Same pads as on Shimano MT200, 300, and 400 calipers.
